# How to "docker login" to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, artifactory

In my Jenkins job I need to login to Artifactory

I've created a global credentials called "Docker_artifactory_creds"

[image]

In job I created bindings for that creds
[image]

to use them in an "Execute shell" step as

```
docker login artifacts.some_custom.com -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD}
```

but that doesn't work (with the same creds passed as row text this line works). I see following logs:

> The following environment variables were **removed by 'Only Keep
> Specified Environment Variables': ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD,
> ARTIFACTORY_USER**, Branch, BUILD_CAUSE, ..., WORKSPACE, WORKSPACE_TMP
> **Removing login credentials for artifacts.some_custom.com**
> Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Why my credentials were ignored/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error from https://plugins.jenkins.io/safe-batch-environment-filter/ plugin

in freestyle: not sure there is a way to do it, only add your job to exclude list in jenkins global config

in Jenkinsfile: you need to wrap your code with

```
keepEnv(['ARTIFACTORY_USER', 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD']) {
  docker login artifacts.some_custom.com -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USER} -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD}
}
```

ps also need to add `withCredentials` or what you use to get this creds to env variable

also jenkins has this feature: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62014
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin/pull/137

assume you use freestyle jenkins job

in job config -> build steps -> execute shell -> advanced -> environment filters -> only keed specified environment variables

there you will find setting `Environment variables to retain` you need to add your variables there

```
Whitespace separated, case insensitive list of environment variables that will be retained, i.e. not removed from the environment of this build step or reset to their default.
```

by default jenkins will remove variable

[image]

Comment: That error occurs even with no SafeBatchEnvironmentFilter plugin installed

Comment: looking, seems jenkins core also has some logic with env filters

Comment: edited my post added description ^